# excel cannot complete this task with available resources

Tags: excel, vba

When i'm trying to copy the data in one of the worksheets into new sheet using the below code in EXCEL 2007, WINDOWS 7, I'm facing with the error "excel cannot complete this task with available resources. choose Less data or close other applications".

when i close all other applications, its showing the same message. How to resolve this issue? Please advise.

```
With ActiveSheet
     .Range("A1").Select
     .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

End With

With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.count))
    NewSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
End With


With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    .Range("A1").Select

End With
```

When i save the xls as .xls (97-2003) its working fine. But i want to run with more data than 65k

Comment: have you tried clearing the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on a newly created excel document and copied 80K rows to a new sheet. 
Your code works...

I did however create it as a macro sub routine and run it multiple times to check.

But you said you saved your document once as a xls. Maybe you got the limitations with it also.

Please and create a new excel document and always save it as xlsx...

Comment: xls is the old file format which have a 65k rows limitation.